# In node.js, do I need to use jQuery twice ? once at the frontend and once on the server?

Tags: node.js

In node.js, do I need to use jQuery twice ? once at the frontend and once on the server ? Sorry for being a noob. Or if I use it once, how will the front end get a copy of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is all about manipulating the DOM. There is no DOM on the server. Why would you use it there?

Generating HTML on the server in node is typically done via a server-side templating engine like handlebars or jade, not via a DOM. They're two very different environments.

Just reference jQuery in a script tag in your generated HTML and use it on the client side.

Comment: Thanks, but what about all the "promise" stuff that can be used using jQuery ... can it not be applied on node.js e.g. stuff written by "Trevor Burnham"

Comment: If you want promises, you're much better off going with the "Q" library. It's the current best-of-breed library for this stuff, and since it's only about promises you won't be loading your server down with lots of DOM stuff you'll never use. See http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/